# Push Notification on android smartphone by Beacon

Tags: android, push-notification, beacon

I am currently working on a beacon project.I want to send a **push notification** on android smartphone when it detect the beacon near by.Now i know how to do it by using **google's near by** and **crome's physical web** or by in any app running in background.i want to do that without using that.so my question is can i do that ?? if yes then how??
(i am a newbie so plz explain in detail it will be helpful)

Answer (score 0):

There is an api for this you can do this thing with the help of that.
go to this [link](https://manager.gimbal.com/) and follow the android integration after login.

Answer (score 0):

**In order to make an Androud phone send notifications in response to beacons, you must have an app installed that is programmed to do so.**  As you mention, there are two typical ways to do this:

1. Build you own app.
2. Use Physical Web beacons with Google Chrome, which essentially offers you a pre-installed app that responds to beacons.

If you do not like either of these options for some reason (explaining why might uncover other options), you will need yet another app installed on the phone.  While some Android phones may have other beacon apps installed (mine does!), as of late 2016, there are no commonly installed apps that provide this functionality.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I dont wont to build an app bcoz I just want to send them a link of some webpage.